# onValueChange not being activated by a script change on load

Tags: google-app-maker

Say I have a dropdown with values X, Y, z, and I have a script taht does something to another dropdown when it is modified (this all works by hand).

But now, sometimes the dropdown value is known previously, so instead of having the user choose the number from the dropdown, it is set by the program.

Now the onValueChange() script is NOT being called, so the logic on the rest of the form isn't happening.

The script that runs and changes the values if the properties already exist is happening on the page onAttach().

From reading the descriptions, onValueChange() SHOULD do something here, but it isnt' being triggered, I added a console line to be sure.

Comment: Are these datasource properties or page properties? The onAttach event is changing the property values or the widget values? I think your problem here is with the page onAttach event, since that will happen before the dropdown attaches and therefore the onValueChange for the dropdown does not yet exist. Will need a bit more detail about the setup and value bindings to help better.

Comment: ah! thanks markus, that makes sense. let me think about it a bit more.

Comment: So I think you are right, that the on attach for the page is running before the dropdown happens. Other than an ugly wait three seconds within the body of the on attach script, is there a cleaner way to trigger the value change? I dont' really want duplicate value change code.

Comment: You could try to set the value/property in the onAttach of the dropdown widget. No guarantee that will work but it's worth a try. Otherwise like I said if you can share a bit more detail I may be able to provide better ideas.

Comment: Make this comment an answer, this worked. Rathe rthan calling the update function on attach of the page I called it on attach of the final element of the form and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically there is an execution order with onAttach events, so if you set a function in the page onAttach event that you would expect to cause an onValueChange event in another element within the page, that event may not get executed because at the time the page attaches and the function executes, the other widget may not yet exist in the DOM tree.

Therefore it is typically better to attach such functions to the individual elements onAttach event vs the page onAttach event.